# How do I make a double-randomizer in AS3?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, random

I want to make a randomize function that loops when the character touches an object (grass), and if that number hits 3, per say, out of 4, it goes to another randomizer which selects a value between 1-5. After it selects a number it should stop the randomizing.

Pseudo-code below

```
If the character is hitting grass
Randomize a number between 1 and 4
  If that number is 3, randomize a number between 1 and 5
  If that number is 1, gotoAndPlay(1, "battle1")
  If that number is 2,....etc
If that number is not a 3, loop the original randomize.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having a hard time understanding exactly what your question is, but it seems like you want something along the lines of:

```
function randomize():int
{
    switch (int(Math.random() * 5))
    {
        case 3: return int(Math.random() * 6); break;
        case 1: gotoAndPlay(1, 'battle1'); break;

        // ...etc
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Which would return a number between 0 and 5 if your first roll was a 3, else return `-1`, meaning you can do something like:

```
var random:int = randomize();
while (random < 0)
{
    // Generate numbers until we go into the second random number roll.
    // ...

    random = randomize();
}
```